# Fix shiny spot after fixing scratch with rubbing nut oil

Tags: wood, furniture, wooden-furniture, table, scratches

My dining room table was scratched and my research said to try to fix this by rubbing a fresh nut into the scratch. Most guides said walnuts, but I had pecans and saw that people said to try that as well.

After a few applications rubbing the nut, the scratch was removed, however there is now a shiny spot where I rubbed the nut.

I've tried washing and polishing the table and the spot, but the shiny spot always comes back. It's not always visible in all light, but you can see it from pretty far away most of the time.

Anything I can do to take the shine our or reduce it without further damaging the table?

[image]

Comment: Note that in the photo it is showing as a _dull_ spot. Rubbing changes the surface texture, which changes how it reflects light. Wear will eventually even this out. If you can't wait, I guess you could try applying a floor wax over the entire area (tear in an inconspicuous corner first) and see if that creates a consistent surface texture to eliminate this difference... Applying the oil as a liquid might or might not have avoided this effect.

Comment: Is the rest of your table finished with some kind of coating, e.g. poly, varnish, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The spot is from the oil in the nut.  To avoid other damage to the surface that cleaners and cleaning actions may cause, I would use the application of time.
Leave it alone and the oil will eventually dry out. Occasionally lightly wiping with a soft cloth may help reduce the time.

Edited since updater OP info:

Try a de-glossing agent such as this:

[Krud Kutter](https://hdsupplysolutions.com/p/qep-heavy-duty-grout-sponge-p131209?ef_id=Cj0KCQiA6fafBhC1ARIsAIJjL8lojd1Yxr2Lbqac48Y8Jc8BFvKpjKfGzJVq44YMg7UFvoIZJZr9pdMaAu4TEALw_wcB:G:s&cid=ppc_all_gl_pfd_Shop%7CHDSS%7CUS%7CHardware&s_kwcid=AL!10728!3!438192856735!!!g!912283916805!!10160878296!110261937988!&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6fafBhC1ARIsAIJjL8lojd1Yxr2Lbqac48Y8Jc8BFvKpjKfGzJVq44YMg7UFvoIZJZr9pdMaAu4TEALw_wcB)

Use it very lightly and only damp on a cloth.

Comment: I use the nut oil several months ago and its been the same. If I clean it goes away for a bit, but I guess once everything else dries out it shows again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the spot disappear, rub out the rest of the table top with your pecan(s) to even the sheen across the entire surface.